# Need help writing a SQL statement

Tags: mysql

I need help writing a SQL statement that will create a SQL view from two different tables that will capture 2 records from each possibility.

For example, if there are three records in the customer table that match `GROUP A` and `STATE` of `NV`, you should only show 2 of the 3 records in the view-but if a customer is in `GROUP A` and `STATE` of `PA` or `GROUP B` and `STATE of NV`, those additional records will also need to be captured in the view.

I am new to SQL.  None of my ideas have worked, so I appreciate any feedback that will help me solve the problem. The following query is what I managed to write:

```
 SELECT customer_table.Customer_ID,
    customer_table.First_Name,
    customer_table.Last_Name,
    customer_table.Email_Address,
    customer_table.STATE,
    customer_table.GROUP_,
    customer_table.Timestamp_,
    product_table.Prod_Name,
    product_table.Prod_desc
FROM customer_table
INNER JOIN product_table ON customer_table.Customer_ID = product_table.Customer_ID
ORDER BY customer_table.STATE,
    customer_table.GROUP_;
```

And here is the view that it generates:

```
+-------------+------------+-----------+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
| Customer_ID | First_Name | Last_Name |   Email_Address    | State | GROUP_ |     Timestamp_      |   Prod_Name    |   Prod_desc    |
+-------------+------------+-----------+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
|           4 | Leon       | Durham    | ldurham@cubs.com   | CA    | A      | 2016-01-25 03:04:22 | Baseball glove | Rawlings glove |
|           1 | Bob        | Dernier   | bdernier@cubs.com  | IL    | A      | 2016-01-25 02:58:45 | Baseball glove | Rawlings glove |
|           2 | Ryan       | Sandberg  | rsandberg@cubs.com | IL    | A      | 2016-01-25 03:02:27 | Baseball glove | Rawlings glove |
|           1 | Bob        | Dernier   | bdernier@cubs.com  | IL    | A      | 2016-01-25 02:58:45 | Jersey         | Chicago jersey |
|           5 | Kieth      | Moreland  | kmoreland@cubs.com | IL    | A      | 2016-01-25 03:05:52 | Baseball glove | Rawlings glove |
|           1 | Bob        | Dernier   | bdernier@cubs.com  | IL    | A      | 2016-01-25 02:58:45 | Hat            | Cubs hat       |
|           7 | Ron        | Cey       | rcey@cubs.com      | YN    | B      | 2016-01-25 03:07:53 | Baseball glove | Rawlings glove |
|           6 | Jody       | Davis     | jdavis@cubs.com    | YN    | B      | 2016-01-25 03:07:08 | Baseball glove | Rawlings glove |
+-------------+------------+-----------+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: You need to decide if you are using mysql or sql-server and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: This should make for a good starting point. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks for that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your best bet is a UNION query. This will stack the results of two seperate `SELECT` statements on top of each other. Furthermore, you can filter the two queries using a `WHERE` clause. The second one will be a bit trickier since you have two conditions, so we'll use an `OR` to seperate them.

```
/* First SELECT finds two records in Nevada for Group A*/
SELECT TOP 2 
    customer_table.Customer_ID,
    customer_table.First_Name,
    customer_table.Last_Name,
    customer_table.Email_Address,
    customer_table.STATE,
    customer_table.GROUP_,
    customer_table.Timestamp_,
    product_table.Prod_Name,
    product_table.Prod_desc
FROM customer_table
INNER JOIN product_table ON customer_table.Customer_ID = product_table.Customer_ID
WHERE customer_Table.GROUP_ = 'A' AND customer_table.STATE = 'NV'

/*UNION ALL will stack the results of these two queries into a single result set*/
UNION ALL

/*Second SELECT finds all records for PA, GROUP A  and NV, GROUP B*/
SELECT 
    customer_table.Customer_ID,
    customer_table.First_Name,
    customer_table.Last_Name,
    customer_table.Email_Address,
    customer_table.STATE,
    customer_table.GROUP_,
    customer_table.Timestamp_,
    product_table.Prod_Name,
    product_table.Prod_desc
FROM customer_table
INNER JOIN product_table ON customer_table.Customer_ID = product_table.Customer_ID
WHERE (customer_table.GROUP_ = 'A' AND customer_Table.STATE = 'PA') OR
    (customer_table.GROUP_ = 'B' AND customer_table.STATE = 'NV')
```

Lastly, that `TOP 2` is SQL Server syntax to say "Return only the top two records for this result set" if this is `MYSQL` then take out the `TOP 2` and stick `LIMIT 2` at the end of that `SELECT` statement instead.

Comment: If the first cursor only has 2 tuples, ok, otherwise I hope you're not in a hurry. A union will join all records in one cursor with each record in the other cursor.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I never used the UNION, so I will have to practice with it.  Would I follow the same structure to the query above if the STATE field can be any of the 50 states and the GROUP range can be from A-Z?

Comment: Something similar should work as your needs change, but as @nicomp suggested, if you get into situations where you need 3 records filter one way, 2 records filtered another way, 5 records filtered yet another way, etc... and you start stacking up many SELECT's, your performance is going to take a hit. But.. UNION is handy in this situation and it will probably suit your needs.